# Replace set of characters inside a string selection in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named `skill` and inside are a string value like this

`{"skill0":"HTML5","skill1":"CSS3","skill2":"PSD-HTML"}`

Note: the number of skills that can be inserted in the column is dynamic so there can sometimes be more than 10.

I would want to remove the set of characters `{"skill0:"`, `"skill1:"` and so on and replace it with just 1, 2 and so on, and also remove the `,` character and print it 1 item per line.

The expected output should look like this

`1 HTML5`

`2 CSS3`

and so on. I have tried using trim and replace but not getting the right output. How would i achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of mysql are you running?

Comment: Doing this in MySQL is really difficult. Do it in an application language. This is JSON, so you can use `json_decode()` in PHP, `json.loads()` in Python. Then you can write a loop.

Comment: It would also be better to normalize your schema. Don't put multiple values in one column, use a many-to-many relation table.

Comment: i am running a MySQL 5.5.42 version. This is a json file that i converted to mysql and would want to restructure the existing data already inside.